# Insert form data in database using wordpress wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a new blog post Plugin in Wordpress form Created Successfully how to Store the form data in database

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'create_books_table');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'truncate_book_table');
add_action('init','book_assets');
add_action("admin_menu", "my_book_plugin_menus");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example of how to insert data to database using $wpdb.

```
  global $wpdb;

  $wpdb->insert( 
    'table_name_here', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1', 
        'column2' => 123 
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%d' 
    ) 
 );
```

Visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins for more .